# How to extract jquery.ajax serialize form parameters in asp.net

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, c#-4.0, json.net

I want to extract form parameters, just like in java `request.getParameter("blah")`

How to do it in C#, presently I serialized my form with jQuery and sending to web method, there I want to extract it

ajax

```
$("#btn").click(function () {
            alert($('#login').serialize());
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Default.aspx/Login",
                data: "{'vals': '" + $('#login').serialize() + "'}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (msg) {
                    TINY.box.show({ html: msg.d, animate: false, close: false, mask: true, boxid: 'success', autohide: 3, top: 200, left: 500 });
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

code-behind

```
[WebMethod]
        public static string Login(String vals)
        {
           //WHAT TO DO HERE SO THAT I CAN EXTRACT FROM THAT STRING
          return vals;
        }
```

I can see the data resurned by msg.d at the client, but thats something like this "uname=1&pwd=2". How to extract it?? please some one help me out. Also is there any way to access the webmethod without making it static?

Comment: use json instead of string. or use split('&') and then split('=') you will get the required values.

Comment: See what i want is something simple, that can be done without changing the client code and with a single line, I have still hope in c#, there will be some method which can do that, not using strings functions. The data it self is sent as query string, then how can i expect it to be in json format. the data is going like this "uname=1&pwd=2"

Comment: use split function of string http://www.dotnetperls.com/split

Comment: Thankyou for ans me. This means the data which ever i am getting to web method is no more in request its just a string? Please give me and example to send and retrive data in json also that wold be great help

Comment: the data should look somethink like this, tell if i am wright.

Comment: [The `.serialize()` method creates a **`text string`** in `standard URL-encoded notation`. It operates on a `jQuery object` representing a `set` of form elements.](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

Comment: contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
 dataType: "json"   remove these

Answer (score 1):

Use json instead of string.
Here are few links which you can follow 
[Sending multiple data parameters with jQuery AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9328743/sending-multiple-data-parameters-with-jquery-ajax)
http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/ajax/Using-jQuery-with-ASP-NET.aspx
http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/96/Handling-JSON-Arrays-returned-from-ASP.NET-Web-Services-with-jQuery

[Jquery Ajax Posting json to webservice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6323338/jquery-ajax-posting-json-to-webservice)