# Sending multiple data with jquery Ajax in php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm unable to understand these answers [Question1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9328743/sending-multiple-data-parameters-with-jquery-ajax) [Question2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10078085/how-to-send-multiple-data-with-ajax-jquery) [Question3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6085649/ajax-multiple-data) so posting my question.
I'm sending an `Ajax` request in PHP file:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click','.show_more',function(){
        var ID = 10;
        var USERID =1;
        $('.show_more').hide();
        $('.loding').show();
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'/ajaxload.php',
            data:'id='+ID & 'user_id=' + USERID,
            success:function(html){
                $('#show_more_main'+ID).remove();
                $('.post_list').append(html);
            }
        }); 
    });
});
```

while receiving Ajax URL 
`id` is received successfully but `user_id` is not getting received

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST["id"]) && ($_POST["user_id"]) && !empty($_POST["id"])){
    echo $_POST["id"];
    echo $_POST["user_id"];
} 
?>
```

Comment: thank you @dlmeetei for improve my questions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace :

```
data:'id='+ID & 'user_id=' + USERID,
```

with:

```
data: {id:ID, user_id:USERID}
```

so your code will look like this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click','.show_more',function(){
        var ID = 10;
        var USERID =1;
        $('.show_more').hide();
        $('.loding').show();
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'/ajaxload.php',
            data: {id:ID, user_id:USERID},
            success:function(html){
                $('#show_more_main'+ID).remove();
                $('.post_list').append(html);
            }
        }); 
    });
});
```

Comment: you welcome @BrijeshPatel and thank as well for acceping the answer

Comment: when i send VARCHAR then it's not working like
USERID = "us1";
data: {id:ID, user_id:USERID}, this line is right 
or where i'm missing some step

Answer (score 0):

pass the data as javascript objects

```
data:{
  id:ID,
  user_id:USERID
}
```

Comment: when i send VARCHAR then it's not working like 
`USERID = "us1";`
`data: {id:ID, user_id:USERID},`
this line is right or where i'm missing some step
please help

Comment: Could you give a little more info about the problem? @Brijesh Patel