# How to post data as an array by Javascript to PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

**JS Code:**

```
$('#addResults').submit(function(e) {
        var user1       = $("#user1").val();
            user2       = $("#user2").val();

        e.preventDefault();
         $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             async: false,
             url: url,
             data: "form=addResults&user1=" + user1 + "&user2=" + user2
           }).success(function( msg ) {
                  $('.success').css("display", "");
                  $(".success").fadeIn(1000, "linear");
                  $('.success_text').fadeIn("slow");
                  $('.success_text').html(msg);
                  setTimeout(function(){location.reload()},1200);
          });

    });
```

**submit.php**

```
         case 'addResults':
            $positions         = $_POST['positions'];
             $ez->addResults($positions);
         break;
```

**function.php**

```
        function addResults($positions) {

         $this->link->query("INSERT INTO `" . $this->prefix . "result` SET race_id = '$league', event = '$event', involved_id = '$involved',

                    evidence_link = '$evidence', description = '$description', reporter_id = '$name', status = '0'");
         echo 'Results saved';
         return;
    }
```

My question: I'd like to store all Users data into an array and push this to the PHP function so I can insert it into the DB there.

Something like:

```
var positions= $("#user1").val(), $("#user2").val();
```

I'm not sure how I format the Data line.

```
data: "form=addResults&user1=" + user1 + "&user2=" + user2
```

Comment: Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9328743/sending-multiple-data-parameters-with-jquery-ajax

Comment: `var positions       = [$("#user1").val(), $("#user2").val()];`  and `data: {'positions':positions}`

Comment: How would I retrieve this in the PHP function?

$positions seems empty when I try this solution.


   
            case 'addResults':
                $positions         = $_POST['positions'];
                 $ez->addResults($positions);
             break;

Answer (score 0):

in PHP:

```
$string = "business_type,cafe|business_type_plural,cafes|sample_tag,couch|business_name,couch cafe";

$finalArray = array();

$asArr = explode( '|', $string );

foreach( $asArr as $val ){
  $tmp = explode( '=', $val );
  $finalArray[ $tmp[0] ] = $tmp[1];
}

print_r( $finalArray );
```

so your JS output could be just one string:

```
data: "form=addResults&user1=" + user1 + "|user2=" + user2
```

Answer (score 0):

The data you pass via ajax seems to be the url you want to send the datas. If you want to pass your data via the url, you should use GET method instead of POST.

In addition you don't use `$position` argument you passed to `addResults` in your function which is weird.